# How do I produce a probability histogram?

Tags: r

I've just started learning R, and was wondering, say I have the dataset quake, and I want to generate the probability histogram of quakes near Fiji, would the code simply be `hist(quakes$lat,freq=F)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A histogram shows the frequency or proportion of a given value out of all the values in a data set. You need a numeric vector as the x argument for `hist()`. There is no `flat` variable in `quakes`, but there is a `lat` variable. `hist(quakes$lat, freq = F)` would show the following:

[image]

This shows the north/south geographical distribution of earthquakes, centering around -20, and, since it is approximately normal (with a left skew) suggests that there is a mechanism for earthquake generation that centers around a specific latitude.

The best way to learn is to try. If you wonder if that would be the way to do it, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at this tutorial on creating [kernel density plots with ggplot](http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/03/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-8-density-plots.html).

Comment: add required info and provide link as a reference.